# What is wrong with this Redux Boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, redux

I have some error.

https://jsbin.com/rapagaw/1/edit?html,js,output

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the
>   context or props of "Connect(Counter)". Either wrap the root component
>   in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(Counter)".

I read https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting

but it is no use.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html pull in the latest version of `React`:

Change

```
<script src="//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.13.3.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.14.3.js"></script>
```